# Passing group name of a user in context and accessing in template in django

Tags: django, templates, django-class-based-views

I have used mixins with class-based views in my django app. I also have created a group named Instructors to allow only user belonging to this group to have certain permissions which are to edit, add and delete a course object.
In the ***ManageCourseList View*** which is responsible for rendering the courses created by the current user, I tried to override the ***get_context_data*** method to pass an additional *'group_list'* argument which contains the groups the user belongs to.
I tried to access it in the template ManageCourseList view renders.
The problem is though the current user belongs to Instructors group but still it renders the else condition data.
Please help,My files:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin,PermissionRequiredMixin

from .models import Course


class OwnerMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(OwnerMixin,self).get_queryset()

        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class OwnerEditMixin(object):
    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(OwnerEditMixin, self).form_valid(form)

class OwnerCourseMixin(OwnerMixin,LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Course
    fields = ['subject','title','slug','overview'] # why use this attribute?
    success_url = reverse_lazy('courses:manage_course_list') # use of it?

class OwnerCourseEditMixin(OwnerCourseMixin,OwnerEditMixin):
    fields = ['subject','title','slug','overview']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('courses:manage_course_list')
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/form.html'

class ManageCourseListView(OwnerCourseMixin,ListView):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ManageCourseListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['group_list'] = self.request.user.groups.all()
        return context
```

list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}My courses{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if group_list.0 == "Instructors" %}
    <h1>My courses</h1>
        <div class="module">
            {% for course in object_list %}
                <div class="course-info">
                    <h3>{{ course.title }}</h3>
                    <p>
                        <a href="{% url 'courses:course_edit' course.id %}">Edit</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'courses:course_delete' course.id %}">Delete</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            {% empty %}
                <p>You haven't created any courses yet.</p>
            {% endfor %}
            <p>
                <a href="{% url 'courses:course_create' %}" class="button">Create new course</a>
            </p>
        </div>

    {% else %}
    <h1>No courses to display</h1>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, that method is pointless as it is; you can simply access `user.groups` in the template.

Secondly, each item in group is a Group object, not a string. So your condition will never succeed; you would need to compare against `group.name`. Also, it's far from certain that instructors will be the first group.

To solve this, I would rewrite your get_context_data to add an instructors flag rather than the group list:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ManageCourseListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user_is_instructor'] = self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Instructors').exists()
    return context
```

and now in the template:

```
{% if user_is_instructor %}
```

Comment: I need to use this group check at most of the places  in my project as mine is a role based one. Is there a way in which I just do it once and then use it everywhere, something like a context_processor otherwise in every view where I do this check it gives an additional query for this check.